# Изменить текст пункта "очередь проверок"

Tags: предложение, локализация, очередь-проверок, термины

Сейчас в шапке сайта для доступа к очередям проверок присутствует ссылка "очередь проверок":

> [image: очередь проверок]

Уже здесь видно, что в названии очередь одна, а в подсказке их много.

Перейдя по ссылке, мы видим страницу, озаглавленную как "Проверка":

> [image: проверка]

Предлагаю привести этот пункт в соответствие с действительностью.

Answer (score 2):

- Кнопка в шапке:

  > Очереди проверок
- Всплывающая подсказка:

  > Помогите улучшить сайт
- Заголовок страницы

  > Очереди проверок

Comment: В целом нормально, но текст подсказки я бы, наверное, оставил прежним. И вопрос с регистром надо более комплексно обсуждать.

Comment: За полную строку «очередь проверок».

Answer (score -1):

Самый простой вариант, как мне кажется, заменить название пункта на одно короткое слово:

> проверка